# How would one limit the Manual Excerpt Length in WP?

Tags: php, wordpress, function

One can control the WP default (**Automatic**) excerpt length of a WP post using the using the following snippet within `functions.php`;

### From the [WP Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_excerpt/)

```
// . Post excerpt adjustment (Auto)
// . ==============================
function wpdocs_custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'wpdocs_custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

> **My question is how do you limit the manual one?**
>
> *You know, the exerpt specifically added by the user themselves?*

(*) *There is an 8 year old question [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6310/how-to-control-manual-excerpt-length), that does provide some context but given the current year and progress WP has made I want to post the question again and receive some clarity on the subject.*

**Added Context: (Edited: 12 March 2019)**

It's not that the original answer to the question posted earlier doesn't work, all be it seems, really clunky. I'm looking for a more simple & robust answer using `exerpt_length` filter. Rather than using something like the following to trim the text; (*If Possible*)

```
function excerpt($limit) {
    return wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
}
```

Comment: Can you share more context? Even if the linked question is some years old, have you tried the given answers? What exactly does not work when using them?

Comment: Certainly, please see the updated question. :)

Comment: Any reason not to just use the `get_the_excerpt()` filter (not to be confused with the function of the same name)?

Comment: @LorenRosen, No real reason per se'. As someone not well versed in WP and learning everyday it strikes me as odd that you can't get the result your looking for with a simple change to `exerpt_length` without using what feels like a "Hacky Method."

Comment: Manipulating `get_the_excerpt` just feels wrong to me. But, as I said I'm learning and I'm trying to understand the difference between good practice and bad practice.

Comment: @Beaniie, even WordPress uses the `get_the_excerpt` filter to generate the automatic excerpt, so it is totally fine to do the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have by default in core, the following filtering:

```
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt' );
```

but within `wp_trim_excerpt()` the trimming is only applied on the post's content, when there's no manual excerpt set.

Here's an untested suggestion for a custom filtering:

```
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', function( $excerpt, $post ) {
    if ( has_excerpt( $post ) ) {
        $excerpt_length = apply_filters( 'excerpt_length', 55 );
        $excerpt_more   = apply_filters( 'excerpt_more', ' ' . '[&hellip;]' );
        $excerpt        = wp_trim_words( $excerpt, $excerpt_length, $excerpt_more );
    }
    return $excerpt;
}, 10, 2 );
```

to apply the similar trimming on manual excerpts.

Hope you can adjust this further to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I got this code from here: https://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-excerpt-length/

```
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', function($length) {
    return 20;
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

This pair of functions will give you control over the excerpt length, including the manual excerpt which is returned if available, otherwise the "excerpt-ized" post_content gets returned. These go in your theme functions file:

```
function get_excerpt_by_id($post_id, $length = NULL) {
  $length = isset($length) ? $length : apply_filters('excerpt_length', 32);
  $p = get_post($post_id);
  return $p->post_excerpt ? build_excerpt_by_length($p->post_excerpt, $length) : build_excerpt_by_length($p->post_content, $length);
}

function build_excerpt_by_length($content, $length = 32) {
  $excerpt = strip_tags(strip_shortcodes($content));
  $words = explode(' ', $excerpt, $length + 1);
  $words = array_slice($words, 0, $length);
  $result = trim(implode(' ', $words));
  $result = preg_replace('/\W*$/', '', $result);
  $more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', '&hellip;');
  if ($result !== '') $result = $content === $result ? $result : $result . $more;
  return $result;
}
```

Then in your templates you can use by calling:

```
get_excerpt_by_id($your_post_id, $preferred_excerpt_length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code

```
$excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); 
$excerpt = substr( $excerpt, 0, 180 ); 
$excerpt_description = substr( $excerpt, 0, strrpos( $excerpt, ' ' ) );
echo $excerpt_description;
```